# Proof that $Pic^0\cong \frac{H^1(X,\mathcal O)}{H^1(X,\mathbb Z)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

Define $Pic^0(X)$ ($X$ complete complex algebraic variety) as the kernel of the first Chern class $c_1:Pic(X)\to H^2(X,\mathbb Z)$. From the long exact sequence arising from the short exponential sequence, $$H^0(X,\mathbb Z)\to H^0(X,\mathcal O)\to H^0(X,\mathcal O^*)\to H^1(X,\mathbb Z)\to H^1(X,\mathcal O)\to H^1(X,\mathcal O^*)\to H^2(X,\mathbb Z)$$

we get that $Pic^0(X)$ is isomorphic to $H^1(X,\mathcal O)$ quotiented by the image of $H^1(X,\mathbb Z)$ in $H^1(X,\mathcal O)$. Griffiths-Harris writes
$$Pic^0(X)\cong \frac{H^1(X,\mathcal O)}{H^1(X,\mathbb Z)}$$
so I understand that the map $H^1(X,\mathbb Z)\to H^1(X,\mathcal O)$ is injective. Why is this?

I have a simple reason for that, i.e. that a complex analysis theorem whose name I have forgotten assures us that $H^0(X,\mathcal O)\to H^0(X,\mathcal O^*)$ via the exponential map is a surjection. So the following map in the long exact sequence is $0$, i.e. the one we are investigation is an injection. Is this the correct reason?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are correct. $H^0(O)=\mathbb{C}, H^0(O^*)=\mathbb{C}^*$ and the exponential map $\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}^*$ is onto.

Comment: Are you assuming that $X$ is compact? I think that $X= \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ is a counterexample otherwise, because $z$ is a global unit on $X$ which is not the exponential of any global function on $X$.

Comment: Edit: X complete.

Comment: Compact will do it, anyway (and in that case Mohan's argument should do).